# Extend Select2 defaults

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I create some default select2 behavior: each select is select2

```
$('select').not('.notSelect2').select2({
    width: "150px",
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: "EMPTY"
});
```

And now i want to change settings for some inputs:

```
function setSelect2Width(control, width) {
    $.extend(true, control.select2.defaults, { width: width });
}
```

This code do nothing for select2. How to change default settings?

[jsfiddle.net/JpvDt/389](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvDt/389)

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with what you have done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values are exactly what the name suggests; values used when nothing else is specified. You are editing the default values after initializing, so the value will not be used for those selects (they will only be used for new selects without an width specified).

So instead do this:

```
function setSelect2Width(control, width) {
    $(control).width(width).select2();
}
```

Comment: The problem is common. "width" is no good example here because it has method. There are important fields that cannot be changed that way: minimumInputLength, url.

Comment: The only way to change those settings is by calling select2() again with the new options. Unfortunately getting all options from a select2 instance isn't possible so you need to store them yourself. I made an example with changing the minimumInputLength: http://jsfiddle.net/F59AV/